# How often does VLC check for updates?

Tags: updates, vlc

I am hoping someone having some experience with VLC can help me out.
Need to know the update check schedule of VLC. Does it check for updates on each launch? Or once daily/weekly/monthly?

I have checked the windows task schedule list but couldn't find any update check scheduled task by VLC.

So how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC do not use task scheduler and such: it checks for updates itself when started.

Frequency is configurable with 3 days as a default value. You can change it in "Options -> Interface" tab in VLC itself.

Comment: Thanks @aland for answering. If I need to change it from the code (to every day by default), do you know which file should I make changes to? Couldn't find it in `src\misc\update.c`

Comment: @foobar The default value for update interval is (for VLC 2.1.15) set in `modules/gui/qt4/qt4.cpp:232`: `add_integer_with_range( "qt-updates-days", 3, 0, 180,` (default 3 days, min. 0 days, max. 180 days).

Comment: Thanks a lot aland for helping. :)